# Elastic Search - Having clause equivalent

Tags: elasticsearch

I have written a faceted query which returns the faceted results (equivalent to Group by in the SQL World).

Now, I would like to get only the faceted results where the count is greater than a particular number (Equivalent to Having clause in SQL)

Any suggestions on the same?

Update : added the query.

I need only the locations where the count is greater than 5. For e.g. US has 7, UK has 5 , and rest has 3 each. So want to return US and UK only in the result.

```
"facets": 
{
   "locations":
   {
        "terms": 
        {
        "field": "location"
        },      
        "facet_filter":
        {         
            "terms": { "location": [ "US", "UK", "DE", "FR", "JP"  ]} 
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: What kind of facet are you using? If you are limiting the size, you could just programmatically remove all the other results.

Comment: Im not sure if Size will fit the requirement. Size is used to limit the number of results returned and not a criteria. I understand, I can programatically filter outside ES but looking for something that is contained within ES.

Comment: haven't seen anything like that.

Comment: I think the upcoming (1.0 release) aggregations functionality might be able to accomplish this using Range criteria from: 5, to: 6 or similar. You can learn more here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3300

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` clauses are not implemented in Elasticsearch yet. You have to handle that client-side.

See https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8110

There are plans to add it, but it has not been done as of May 2015.